# Find the derivative of $\frac{d}{dt} (\int_0^t xf(x)dx)$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

I was going through the solved example 2.d in Sheldon Ross "A First Course in Probability 8th Edition" Chapter 5, and i got stuck on a reduction involving calculus differentiation.

with regards to specifics of the problem as per the equation below, x and t are non-negative variables, and c, k are constants. f(x) represents probability density function, F(x) represents the cumulative probability density function.

$$
ExpectedCost = ct\int_0^t f(x)dx - c\int_0^t xf(x)dx + k\int_t^\infty xf(x)dx -kt\int_t^\infty f(x)dx
$$

The step i am unable to comprehend is the derivative of $ExpectedCost$ with respect to t, which, as per the book, yields:

$$
\frac{d}{dt} (ExpectedCost) = ctf(t) + cF(t) - ctf(t) - ktf(t) + ktf(t) - k[1-F(t)]
$$

My own calculations differ from those of the book:

Integral#1:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} (\int_0^t f(x)dx) = f(t)
$$

Integral#2:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} (\int_t^\infty f(x)dx) = -f(t)
$$

Integral#3:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} (\int_0^t xf(x)dx) \\
= \frac{d}{dt} (xF(x)|_0^t - \int_0^t F(x)dx) \\
= \frac{d}{dt} (xF(x)|_0^t) - \frac{d}{dt} (\int_0^t F(x)dx) \\
= \frac{d}{dt} (tF(t)) - \frac{d}{dt} (\int_0^t F(x)dx) \\
= F(t) + tf(t) - F(t) \\
= tf(t)
$$

Integral#4:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} (\int_t^\infty xf(x)dx) \\
= \frac{d}{dt} (xF(x)|_t^\infty - \int_t^\infty F(x)dx) \\
= \frac{d}{dt} (xF(x)|_t^\infty) - \frac{d}{dt} (\int_t^\infty F(x)dx) \\
= \frac{d}{dt} (-tF(t)) - \frac{d}{dt} (\int_t^\infty F(x)dx) \\
= -F(t) -tf(t) - (-F(t)) \\
= -tf(t)
$$

As per my calculations, the derivative of the $ExpectedCost$ with respect to t, comes to zero. My guess is that i am going wrong with regards to the calculation of derivatives of Integrals #3 and #4. Please help correct my mistake.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think you are forgetting the factor $ct$ in front of your first integral and the factor $-kt$ in front of your last integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first term is not just Integral #1, but $ct\int_0^t f(x)dx$, where $c$ is a constant, but $t$ isn't. So although your derivative of Integral #1 is correct, it is **NOT** the derivative of the first term. Finding the derivative of this term requires the Product Rule:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left[ct\cdot\int_0^t f(x)dx\right]=\frac{d}{dt}[ct]\cdot\int_0^t f(x)dx+ct\cdot\frac{d}{dt}\left[\int_0^t f(x)dx\right]=c\int_0^t f(x)dx+ctf(t)=cF(t)+ctf(t),$$
since $F(t)=\int_0^t f(x)dx$.

Also, your derivative of the last term is incorrect for the same reason.

Answer (score 2):

Is that not that you skip the t in the front of the integrals? They are also part of the derivative.