# Calculus question from Ross 'A first Course in Probability'.

Tags: calculus, probability

My question comes from example 2d of section 5.2 in the 8th edition. This example involves some calculus, which is discussed in the question: [Find the derivative of $\frac{d}{dt} (\int_0^t xf(x)dx)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2190901/find-the-derivative-of-fracddt-int-0t-xfxdx)

I follow the argument in the referenced post right up to the 4th line of integral 4. Specifically, the aim is to find $\frac{d}{dt}(\int_t^\infty xf(x) dx)$, where $f(t)$ is a pdf such that $f(t) = 0$ whenever $t<0$ . Using integration by parts we obtain $\frac{d}{dt}(xF(x)|^\infty_t) - \frac{d}{dt}(\int_t^\infty F(x)dx)$ (where $F(t)$ is the cdf). The expression on the left is then claimed to be equal to $\frac{d}{dt}(-t(F(t))$, but I don't understand why this is true. If $xF(x)|^\infty_t$ is understood as the limit of $nF(n) - tF(t)$ as $n$ tends to infinity, why does this limit exist? I feel like I'm missing something obvious here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably you are assuming that $\int^\infty_0 xf(x)\,dx<\infty$. $$ \frac{d}{dt}\Big(\int^\infty_t xf(x)\,dx\Big)=- t f(t)$$. Is this what you are trying to get at?

Comment: You don't need integration by parts. Define $\phi(t)=\int^\infty_t x f(x)\,dx$. Use definition of derivative, that is compute $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\phi(t + h)-\phi(t)}{h}$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz We're not explicitly told that $\int_0^\infty xf(x) dx$ is finite, though it seems a reasonable assumption in context, and does greatly simplify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, assumed that (1) $\int^\infty_0 x f(x)\,dx <\infty$. for simplicity, assume (2) that  the density function $f(x)$ is continuous. It is to be shown that
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\Big(\int^\infty_t xf(x)\,dx\Big)=- t f(t)$$
It is easier in my opinion to estimate the derivative directly from definition. Let $\phi(t)=\int^\infty_t x f(x)\,dx$. For $h>0$
$$\frac{\phi(t+h)-\phi(t)}{h}=-\frac{1}{h}\int^{t+h}_t x f(x)\,dx$$
Continuity of $f$ implies continuity of the function $t\mapsto t f(t)$ is also continuous. Notice that
$$\frac{\phi(t+h)-\phi(t)}{h} -(-t f(t))=-\Big(\frac{1}{h}\int^{t+h}_t xf(x)\,dx - tf(t)\Big)=-\Big(\frac{1}{h}\int^{t+h}_t \big(xf(x) - tf(t)\big)\,dx\Big)$$
By continuity, for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that $|x-t|<\delta$ implies $|x f(x)-t f(t)|<\varepsilon$. Thus, if $|h|<\delta$ one gets
$$\Big|\frac1h \int^{t+h}_t\big(xf(x) - tf(t)\big)\,dx\Big|\leq \frac{1}{h}\int^{t+h}|(xf(x) - tf(t)|\,dx\leq\varepsilon$$
This shows that $$\lim_{h\rightarrow0+}\frac{\phi(t+h)-\phi(t)}{h}=-t f(t)$$
A similar argument shows that
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0-}\frac{\phi(t+h)-\phi(t)}{h}=-t f(t)$$

---

**Comment:** Assumption (2) is to avoid measure theoretic technicalities (Lebesgue points, almost surely convergence, etc)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. We are told that $f$ is continuous, but not that $\int^\infty_0 xf(x) dx<\infty$, though this does seem like it is likely intended, as the example doesn't really make sense if it is not. I'm still curious about the integration by parts based argument though. Is there a simple thing I'm missing that makes it work out as described?

Comment: With assumption (1) we can also get the main result by noting that $\int_t^\infty xf(x) dx = C - \int_0^t xf(x)dx$, where $C$ is the finite value of $\int_0^\infty xf(x)dx$. Then differentiating wrt $t$ gives $-tf(t)$ as required.

Comment: @greens: integration by parts muddles the simplicity of what you want to achieve.  $$\begin{align}\int^\infty_t xf(x)\,dx&=-\int^\infty_t x d(1-F(x))=x(1-F(x))|^\infty_t +\int^\infty_t(1- F(x))\,dx\\ &=-t(1-F(t))+\int^\infty_t(1-F(x))\,dx\end{align}$$ The issue is that  (1) you have to justify why is $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x(1-F(x))=0$, and (2) you have to differentiate  $\int^\infty_f(1-F(x))\,dx$. This can be done using the definition of derivative as I did in my solution. But if that is the case, why not do that from the very begining?

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean about the integration by parts argument. It just adds an unnecessary step and makes the overall argument harder to understand by hiding the fact that what is really important is the finiteness of $\int^\infty_0 xf(x) dx$.

Comment: @greens: Exactly. Justifying $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x(1-F(x))=0$ is not hard but not a trivial thing (that is why the assumption of $E[X]<\infty$ is needed) In an case, to me changing a simple problem by a harder one, unless there is something extra to be gained, is not worth my while.